# How do I connect my login screen to a specific website & database to accept usernames and passwords?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a login page for an app that I am working on and in order to get the login page up I followed this tutorial(http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2012/03/iphoneios-programming-login-screen-post-data-url-parses-json-response/). I want to know why the login page that I created isn't working. I'm pretty sure it may have something to do with connecting the database to the app. Any clues on how I could do this ? I know the username and password works because I tried it on the website and it worked perfectly. Any clue as to why it won't work in the app ? Thanks for the help !

Here is a snippet of my code:

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
    @try {

        if([[username text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[password text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
        } else {
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[username text],[password text]];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thespot2g.com/login"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
            if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

                SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
                NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
                NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"%d",success);
                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];

                } else {

                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
                }

            } else {
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
    }
}

- (IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender {
    [username resignFirstResponder];
    [password resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Here is what i get in the console after failing to login with correct credentials

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US">
  <meta name="author" content="Innovatrix Labs, LLC">
  <meta name="copyright" content="The Spot2g, LLC">  
  <meta name="description" content="connecting nightlife enthusiasts with their favorite venues through a real time feed of drink specials, ent, waits, cover charges, and etc!">
  <meta name="keywords" content="The Spot2g, Spot2g, Bar Specials, Drink Specials, Awesome Venues, Innovatrix Labs">
  <meta name="city" content="State College, Williamsport">
  <meta name="state" content="Pennsylvania">
  <title>The Spot2g</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://thespot2g.com/favicon.ico"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://thespot2g.com/styles/spot2g.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://thespot2g.com/styles/bootstrap.css"/>
  <script src="http://thespot2g.com/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://thespot2g.com/scripts/jquery.accordion.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://thespot2g.com/scripts/homepage.js"></script>
  <script src="http://thespot2g.com/scripts/loginajax.js"></script>
  <script src="http://thespot2g.com/scripts/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
  <script src="http://thespot2g.com/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Google Analytics 
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-26344176-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

  </head>
<body>
 <div id="page-wrapper">
  <div id="header">
   <div class="header-wrap">
    <div class="header-wrap-2">     
     <div class="logo">
      <a href="http://thespot2g.com/home"><img src="http://thespot2g.com/images/logo.png" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;" alt="Spot2G" /></a>
     </div> <!-- logo -->
        <div id="navigation-top">
<div class="user-controls"> 
 <ul>
   <li><a href="http://thespot2g.com/login">Log In</a></li> | 
   <li><a href="http://thespot2g.com/account/register">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--//user-controls -->

</div><!--//navigation-top -->
    </div><!--//header-wrap-2 -->
   </div><!--//header-wrap -->

  </div><!-- //#header -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="featured-special">
    <p> <a href="http://thespot2g.com/venues/id/38">Follow us on twitter: @TheSpot2g !! at TheSpot2g</a> </p> 
  </div>


  <div id="content">
    <div id="content-left">
    <div id="navigation-side">
    <div class="navigation">
     <ul>
      <li class="accordion-parent"><a href="#">Venues</a></li>
      <ul class="accordion-content" style="max-height:235px; overflow-x:hidden;">

        <li><a href="/venues/id/61">Arena Bar & Grill</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/68">Autoport</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/34">Bar Bleu</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/71">Brewery</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/46">Cafe 210</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/59">Champs Sports Grill</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/31">Chrome</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/30">Darkhorse</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/51">Gigi's</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/47">Gingerbread Man</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/26">Hi-way Pizza</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/25">Home Delivery Pizza</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/56">Indigo</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/23">Inferno</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/42">Kildare's</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/70">Levels</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/57">Lions Den</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/19">Mad Mex</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/43">Mt. Nittany Inn</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/18">Otto's Pub and Brewery</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/50">Phyrst</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/64">Phyrst Upstairs</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/16">Pickles</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/60">Pletcher's Beer Distributor</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/55">Rotelli's</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/63">Shandygaff</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/11">Sharkies</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/15">The Rathskellar</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/13">The Saloon</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/38">TheSpot2g</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/58">W.R. Hickey Beer Distributor</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/62">Westside Stadium Bar and Grill</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/8">Z Bar</a></li><li><a href="/venues/id/7">Zeno's</a></li>      </ul>
      <li class="accordion-parent"><a href="#">Whats Going On?</a></li>
        <ul class="accordion-content">
            <li><a href="/about"> What is The Spot2g? </a> </li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/thespot2g" target="_blank"> Follow us on Twitter! </a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Spot2g-LLC/160013764093417" target="_blank"> Like us on Facebook! </a> </li> 
        </ul>
     </ul>
    </div> <!-- navigation -->  
</div><!--//#navigation-side --> 
 <div class="content-box">
     <a href="http://www.blaisealexanderhyundaimazda.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://thespot2g.com//images/uploads/promo/1361154289.jpg" width="230px"/></a>
 </div><!--//content-box -->


 <div class="content-box">
     <a href="http://www.wrhickey.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://thespot2g.com//images/uploads/promo/1363833306.jpg" width="230px"/></a>
 </div><!--//content-box -->


</div><!--//#content-left -->
  <div id="main-content">   
    <div id="form-login">
<form action="http://thespot2g.com/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div class="form-title"><p>Login to the Spot2g</p></div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Username</label>
        <div><input type="text" name="login-username" value="" id="login-username"  /></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Password</label>
        <div><input type="password" name="login-password" value="" id="login-password"  /></div>
    </li>
    <li id="login-submit">
        <div><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"  /></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>The Username field is required.</p>
<p>The Password field is required.</p>
    </li>
</ul>   
</form> 
</div><!--//#form-login -->
  </div><!-- //#main-content -->
    <div id="content-right">
 <div class="content-box">
  <h2> Featured Venue </h2>
        <a href="/venues/id/47"> <img src="/images/uploads/1361328262.jpg" width="230px"/> </a>
 </div><!--//content-box-->

 <div class="content-box">
     <a href="http://www.pletchersbeer.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://thespot2g.com//images/uploads/promo/1364503058.jpg" width="230px"/></a>
 </div><!--//content-box -->

 <div class="content-box">
     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Good-Evil-Tattoos/105461496181423?ref=ts&fref=ts" target="_blank"><img src="http://thespot2g.com//images/uploads/promo/1377425552.jpg" width="230px"/></a>
 </div><!--//content-box -->

 <div class="content-box">
     <a href="http://www.michaelrobertssilverscissors.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://thespot2g.com//images/uploads/promo/1379012957.jpg" width="230px"/></a>
 </div><!--//content-box -->

</div><!--//#content-right -->
 </div><!--//#content -->
    </div><!--//#content-wrapper -->
    <div id="footer">  
        <p>&copy; 2012 <a href="http://thespot2g.com/">The Spot2g, LLC</a> All Rights Reserved.</p>
        <p>Powered by <a href="http://www.innovatrixlabs.com">Innovatrix Labs</a></p>
   </div><!-- //#footer -->
  </div> <!-- //#page-wrapper -->
 </body>
</html>

2013-10-28 23:55:24.281 Spot2G[1069:a0b] (null)
2013-10-28 23:55:24.282 Spot2G[1069:a0b] 0
```

Comment: What response are you getting? What errors are printed?

Comment: @ckhan it just tells me that the login has failed even though I am using the correct credentials

Comment: Even your code above has multiple failure branches. Which one, exactly? What does your server log says? Was it a failure to connect, a 40x, a 50x? An unparseable response?

Comment: it's weird I get a bunch of xml/html code, i'll edit my original post and post so you know what I'm talking about

Comment: Note that it is not a good idea to load external mechanisms (like webviews) for subscriptions or authentication. Apple may reject your app for that. It is better to expose a service on the server side and use a form within your app.

Comment: @NikosM. okay, so how would I go about exposing a service on the server side and using a form in my app ? I'm sorta new to this

Comment: Try a websearch about JSON service and iOS JSON parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your specific issue, but can offer up some general advice:

**Use OAuth**

To save users having to log in with the username & password credentials on every use of the app, you might want to look at securing your app using the OAuth security protocol. This is how Facebook, Twitter, Dropbox, Instagram, etc works.

The basis of the OAuth protocol is:

- User authenticates once using their user-name and password credentials.
- The authentication provider assigns a token to the app that can be used for subsequent requests.
- This token has an expiry date. It can also be revoked by the user, by visiting a site, making it secure in the event of a lost device.

You can set up your own OAuth provider on the backend and a consumer using eg GTMOAuth2. You can also use one of the above (Facebook, Dropbox, Instagram, etc) as a single-sign-on provider.

**Single Sign-on:**

- Use the client SDK (Facebook, LinkedIn, etc) or a generic OAuth library to obtain an access token.
- Send this access token to the backend.
- The backend will attempt authentication using the token. If successful, assign a session for x minutes.

Comment: Sorry I'm sorta new to all this, how difficult is it to secure my app using the OAuth security protocol ?

Comment: It can be quite challenging - there's loads of config options in OAuth, as well two major spec versions. Depending on what you are doing, it might be an unnecessary distraction . . Using an SDK like LinkedIn, Facebook, as a single-sign-on provider is somewhat easier. . . however, if you plan on publishing to the AppStore it can give a very professional finish.

Comment: I actually do plan on submitting to the app store so it's probably necessary

Comment: Hi Erv Noel, did you make it work for you? I am trying to do the same but can not figure out how to make it.....